# Trying to get the value in vba from the combo box selection in a form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a form in which there is a combobox that holds all the badge numbers (example of a badge # : 12345) but when I try to assign it to a variable in vba it gives me the following error:
run-time error '6'
overflow

But when I go to debug it shows that Combo529.Value = 12345 but it wont assign it to my variable and gives the error

```
Private Sub reportRecord_Click()
Dim badgeNum As Integer
badgeNum = Combo529.Value

reportRecord.Value = getReport(badgeNum)
End Sub
```

and here is the code for the getReport() function:

```
Function getReport(badge As Integer)

Dim yearNow As Integer
yearNow = year(Date)

Dim report As String

report = badge & "-" & yearNow & "-"

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 3
If Not IsNull(DLookup("Badge_ID", "Employee_Self_Assessment", "Report_ID = ' " & report & "0" & i & "'")) Then

    getReport = 0
    
    Else
    
    Next i
    
    getReport = 1
    
End If
    

End Function
```

Comment: Try declaring variable as Long.

Comment: Perfect that worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Presume Badge_ID is an autonumber or long integer field and apparently the value is too large for Integer variable. Declare the variable as Long. Or a Variant type should work - variables not explicitly declared will default to Variant.